# JQuery Ajax function called twice first call working, while second is not

Tags: jquery, ajax

Platform: spring
I'm using ajax call to same function, first for a blur function and then for a click function.
But the blur function is working while the click function is not. I changed the name of the function i called and then it's working fine.

Please help me to find a solution. I want to send an ajax call to the function 'isValidPassword' on a blur and and a click function.

On both click and blur i have to do the code below.

```
if (oldPassword != "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'isValidPassword.html?oldpassword=' + oldPassword,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "Valid") $("#oldpassworderror").html(data);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: My problem. I'm trying to do a "change password"  in a page. So first i have to check the password entered is same as the saved password. For that i'm using the ajax call. If the password entered is not same as the old password I have to show a error message in tab out(blur) and also the same message should be shown when the user clicks the "save"(click) button. But now the ajax call is working only on blur function and not on click.

Here is the "isValidPassword" function code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/isValidPassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String isValidPassword(@RequestParam("oldpassword") String oldpassword,
            User user, HttpSession session ) throws Exception {
        String login = (String)session.getAttribute("userName");
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(oldpassword);
        String message = null;
        // Check whether old password is valid and
        // give a message in front end
        if (userService.isValidPassword(user)) {
            message = "Valid";
        } else {
            message = "Incorrect old password";
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: show your html code of on chane and on blur

Comment: `its working fine` ..you mean you got the solution ??? if not then post the realated code..the code you posted here is not related at all

Comment: Are you aware that your code is asynchronous? That means, your "success" function doesn't run immediately but some time in the future?

Comment: @rajesh i have to call the same function on blur and click. The thing is when a tab out is happening and when someone tried to click a save button i need to show the same error message

Comment: @bipen it is working fine if i create a duplicate of same function i have to call, not when the function is called twice, once from blur and then from click.

Comment: @richard i dont sir, can u please explain?

Comment: instead of calling ajax just alert('something') and check it whether function is working or not

Comment: @user2071789 how are you calling the click function... post the click code..

Comment: @rajeshkakawat yeah, i tried, the function is working. It is not working only the ajax call is given both from click and blur functions.

Comment: @user2071789 - "success" function is a callback - system calls it automatically after the server returns a response. But other Javascript code runs on, while waiting for a response. If response doesn't arrive, or arrives without "success" state, the code never runs.

Comment: @bipen on click function the above code is happening.

Comment: may be you forgot to set `oldPassword` in click :) :)

Comment: @bipen copied the same thing to click too. So.. :)

Comment: try to alert something in your success function

Answer (score 1):

try caching..

```
if (oldPassword != "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'isValidPassword.html?oldpassword=' + oldPassword,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false, // disable caching
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "Valid") $("#oldpassworderror").html(data);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test this code properly, you shall prepare the AJAX call this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'isValidPassword.html?oldpassword=' + oldPassword,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

so you can observe if the problem is on client or server side.

Comment: "success" alert is showing on one case, but not on the second time.

Comment: No. no messages on second time.

Comment: Then there is a high probability that the problem is outside the code you posted.